# Why has this piece of javascript stopped working in Firefox but not in other browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser

I have a simple html form with a textbox and button.

Enter some text, press the button and Ajax returns some data which appears below the textbox.

It has been working well for many months but has recently stopped working in FF although it still works fine in Vivaldi, Chrome and IE. In FF, nothing at all appears.

Am I doing something silly that is no longer allowed in FF.

Relevant code fragment below.
Thanks

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

 $("#textbox").val("");
 $("#textbox").focus(); 

$('#textbox').keypress(function (e) { //When in textbox, Enter clicks 'check'
 var key = e.which;
 if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
  {
 $('#search').click();
 return false;  
  }
}); 


$('#search').on('click', function() {

 $("#hlist").load("sg_ajaxGetHymns.php",{hm: $('#textbox').val()});
 $("#textbox").val("");
}); // end of textbox action

});

</script>
<div id="hy2">
<p><b>Enter name or number</b></p>

<div id="tab-form">
<form id="mainform">
 <div id="hy3">
 <input id="textbox" type="text"/>
 <input value="Search" type="button" id="search"/>
 </div>
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>

<div id="hlist">
</div>
```

Comment: What is your version of Firefox?

Comment: Hello SteveG! Could you please check the console for any error in Firefox? :)

Comment: your code works for me in FF. Have you checked in the network tab what the result of your load opperation is?

Comment: I think its because the `e.which` is now outdated for Mozilla. Checkout [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) for more info.

Comment: FF is v71.0. No console errors. Load operation works. I'll look at e.which alternatives.